# Path in css to call background image in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

i load my css like this

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/home/css/style.css');?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
```

Now I want to call a background image from my style CSS something like this:

```
background: url(../assets/img/home/images/cover.jpeg)no-repeat center;
```

But this doesn't work

Can someone tell me how I call the image file from CSS?

My file structure is assets/img/home/images/cover.jpeg

My css structure is assets/css/home/css/style.css

Comment: Have you tried `background: url('./assets/img/home/images/cover.jpeg')no-repeat center;` or `background: url('assets/img/home/images/cover.jpeg')no-repeat center;`

Comment: Use `background-image` except `background`

Comment: Can you make sure if the image file exist with .jpg or .jpeg? this could be problem

Comment: Please provide your file structure so that we can help you

Comment: check my answer below if it works

Comment: it doesn't work @claudios

Comment: place your comment below my answer so that I'll be notified directly. Check my edited answer. it should work

Comment: Inside the console window of your browser you should see where it's looking for it, then you should be able to adjust accordingly. At first glance, the link in your .css file should be something like ../../../../img/home/images/cover.jpeg if you go relative, or just eventual_dirs_from_root/assets/img/home/images/cover.jpeg if you go absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update your question and put your file structure.
Assuming that your `css file` is inside the `css folder` and `image file` inside `img folder` within the `assets directory`.

Call html helper inside your controller:

`$this->load->helper('html');`

How to call the stylesheet:

```
<?php echo link_tag('assets/css/home/css/style.css'); ?>
```

Try to change the url like this:

```
background: url(../img/home/images/cover.jpeg)no-repeat center;
```

Comment: I think it can't use link_tag() @claudios

Comment: @DavidWinalda, add the html helper inside your controller. check above edited code

Answer (score 0):

Your original question does not include your file structure for CodeIgniter, but I am fairly confident your relative path is simply incorrect.

If your setup is to remove the index.php from your URLs via mods_rewrite, your rewrite rules should still allow for direct access to the assets folder via URL. If this is not so, you need to correct this first. If you leave index.php in your URLS, then this step does not apply.

In either case, you're URL needs to be relatively based off of the index.php; I am going to assume that your thought process was to use ../ to go up one directory from views and then up to assets inside your application directory. Do you not need to go up a level because you are already in the project root.